# Adding ratio to a SSRS matrix

Tags: reporting-services, expression, ssrs-tablix, calculated-field

I want to add an  expression to each row in the ratio column. I want to divide row total by group total and show that amount in the ratio column for each row. For the first row  of ratio column it should be 11/44.

[image]

My design tab has the following design.

[image]

Comment: My scope was wrong .I corrected it. It worked. Thank you so much

Comment: Hi Thanu, if the answer I gave solved the problem, please could you mark it as the answer - this closes the question off. Glad it worked in the end!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Take the formula in your total row (something like `Sum(Fields!Survey1.Value)`) and add the group name over which you want to sum your total, giving something like `Sum(Fields!Survey1.Value,"ExamGroup")`. That should allow you to access the total at each row of the group, so you can get the ratio of each row with something like this:

```
Fields!Survey1.Value / Sum(Fields!Survey1.Value,"ExamGroup")
```

Comment: You forgot to SUM the numerator in the example expression (though it's mentioned in the text).

Comment: I wrote the following expression but it gives me an error message . My column groups name in the design tab  is exam_type_name.=Count(Fields!exam_response_ID.Value)/Count(Fields!exam_response_ID.Value,"exam_type_name")